# Logstash - Can choose not to forward a log based on data?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

Just learning how to use Logstash - goddamn there's a lot to learn on this :D

In my setup, I have CEF data being sent to my logstash. 
Some cef events are just "statistic" information about the tool that is sending the cef events.

I want logstash to NOT send on these events. Is that possible?

Here is some psuedo code of what I think it would look like.

```
input { 
  udp { 
    port => 9001 
    codec => cef
}

filter { 
  if 'stat_heading' contains "Statistic Information" do not forward to elasticsearch 
}

output { 
  elasticsearch { 
    host => ["192.168.0.20:9200"] 
}
```

Could someone point me in the correct direction?

**Edit**

Okay - So i see the Filter does have an optional for IF Conditions. I'm going to read into this more, and when i get a working solution I'll post it.

**Edit**

got it working. Added solution in comments below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try drop plugin to skip some data if it gets to filter

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-drop.html

Comment: Hey Arun, Yeah you are absolutely correct! I added the solution below - but i'll let mark yours as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've found my own answer to this.

You need to add in the conditional If statements, and if an event value matches some value then drop the event.

```
input { 
  udp { 
    port => 9001 
    codec => cef
}

filter { 
  if "Some string here" in [myheader] {
    drop {}
}

output { 
  elasticsearch { 
    host => ["192.168.0.20:9200"] 
}
```